# How to track clicks in specific links?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, analytics, ahoy

I am using the ahoy gem. I found out that there are ways like `ahoy.trackClicks();` to track clicks. But it also tracks clicks on dropdown and signin and signout. I only want to track clicks on specific page. I have a page with ads and clicking on that ads will lead to new tab with external page.

Though the above js code track it, is it possible just to track clicks on ads and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

In the ahoy docs, there is a `ahoy.trackClicks()` function where you could track clicks based on class - https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.js#clicks

```
<div class="trackable-ad">AD #1</div>
<div class="trackable-ad">AD #2</div>
```

Comment: i added class to my a tag and still it records every clicks. Even it records the click when I closed the alert box.